# Is it possible to run one concrete validation using Hibernate Validation

Tags: java, hibernate, validation

We were using Hibernate Validation in a project for a long time and it works great.
But i want to know if it is possible to run only certain validation on demand, not when calling valid() on a validator or before saving.
For example i have a class:

```
@ValidationOne
@ValidationTwo
@Entity
public class MyClass{
  ...

}
```

ValidationOne and ValidationTwo are defined by a interface as Validation Api says:

```
@Target({ ElementType.TYPE, ANNOTATION_TYPE })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = ValidationOneValidator.class)
@Documented
public @interface ValidationOne {

  String message() default "{ValidationOne.invalid.message}";

  Class<?>[] groups() default {};

  Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

And the validator classes follow Validation API specs:

```
public class ValidationOneValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidationOne, MyClass>{
  ...
}
```

Those validations runs fine. But now i want to know if the condition on ValidationOne is true in my controller, on a specific method. I don't want to duplicate the ValidationOneValidator code. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the `groups()` property on the annotation definition? It allows you to use classes to specify what validations you want to run.

For example, let's assume this:

```
public class SingleRun {}

@ValidationOne(groups={SingleRun.class, javax.validation.groups.Default.class})
@ValidationTwo
@Entity
public class MyClass{...}
```

This allows you to run the single validation like this:

```
javax.validation.Validator validator = ...;
MyClass myClass = ...;
validator.validate(myClass, SingleRun.class);
```

When you validate manually, you can specify the validations to run via the group classes. If you don't specify one, the default group is assumed.